# Printing through hplip does not work after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: printing, 15.04, hp, hplip

I have the HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw all-in-one printer-scanner. In Ubuntu 14.10 I had it up and running using the hplip 3.15.7 (the latest from hplipopensource.com, not the repositories).

After upgrading Ubuntu to 15.04 the printing stopped working. I tried to remove and setup the printer again, no luck. I tried to remove hplip and install it again, no luck. Running `hp-check` gives no error whatsoever. What happens when I print something (e.g. test page from hp device manager) is following:

- I issue printing (clicking print somewhere)
- Printing ...
- Started a job ...
- Job completed ...
- Printing stopped ...

all combined taking about 10 seconds. And when I look at job queue in the device manager there is one job with status "Stopped".

I am in the `lp` group.

Scanning works fine.

I really don't know where the problem could be because I think I checked everything (but apparently not). I need your help.

Comment: I'm having the same problems with a Color LaseJet MFP M277dw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I issued a [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1491577) and received a [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1491577/comments/2) there:

> This is an issue with hplip 3.15.7 drivers. I have provided the patch for the same in the bug report
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1476920.
>   This issue will be resolved in our next version of hplip.
>
> If you wish to go back to hplip-3.15.6. You can download the drivers from
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.15.6/hplip-3.15.6.run/download
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience.

So it is the bug in hplip 3.15.7. Using the older 3.15.6 solves this problem. I recently upgraded to 3.15.9 and it works as well.

Comment: I have `lplip` `Version: 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4`, but have similar with my HP Laserjet printer.